# Time to stop using [webtools]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The [webtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webtools) tag currently has 32 questions and 5 followers. I don't think it serves any purpose. So, time for the standard questions:

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

I'd say no. Some of the questions are asking for recommendations for tools ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39057704/online-tool-snippet-code-quality-analysis), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36685161/what-tools-can-retrieve-documents-given-a-sites-directory), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711190/online-tool-to-manage-svn)) or why a certain webtool doesn't work ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33757652/why-google-development-check-url-for-mobile-devices-doesnt-work)) or some that have nothing to do with webtools ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577755/how-to-debug-on-local-jboss-as-7-using-eclipse-3-7), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031695/how-and-where-to-add-a-robots-txt-file-to-an-asp-net-web-application))

2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Some questions are, some are not. The tag is often used by users looking for a webtool (which is off topic). But there are also users asking why a certain tool doesn't behave as expected. This makes it hard to judge, but I'd say that the on-topic questions don't lose anything when the tag is removed.

3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

Again, I have to say it doesn't. The tag is so ambiguous (user looking for a webtool, user is using a webtool) that it doesn't add any information to the post

4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

The word web-tool means the same in all common contexts, sure. But the tag doesn't. It has been used for topics so different that one cannot be sure anymore what a users means with the tag.

**EDIT:**

@TinyGiant pointed out that webtools is a project from eclipse. I did not know this. But I do think that users are unaware of this. So I'd suggest retagging those questions to something like [eclipse-wtp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-wtp)

Comment: [webtools is a thing though](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/). We don't throw out a tag just because it is misused. Otherwise we might as well get rid of the Java tag because new JavaScript users have a tendency to tag their questions incorrectly with Java

Comment: @TinyGiant but is the tag about that? I see a Visual Studio question with the tag.

Comment: @Braiam Like I said, I see JavaScript questions with the Java tag frequently

Comment: @TinyGiant but in proportion, how many js question you see with the java tag?

Comment: That does not matter in my opinion. We do not get rid of tags because they are being used incorrectly. We correct the usage, and the usage guidance if necessary. This warrants a tag clean up, not a burnination.

Comment: @TinyGiant no, we do correct mistagged questions. If that ends up eradicating the tag, that's not a bug, but a feature.

Comment: Ok, but there are questions in there that are about the eclipse webtools product, so unless you edit it out of questions where it is relevant, the tag will still be left behind

Comment: @TinyGiant, I hadn't come across the webtools link you posted. But I think it would be best to retag those questions to something like `eclipse-webtools`.

Comment: @TinyGiant, there is already a tag for those questions [eclipse-wtp]. So I'd suggest retagging to that.

Comment: @TinyGiant The tag excerpt and wiki should reflect that usage. The people using Java for JavaScript are a lost cause in many ways, not least of which because that the tag excerpt and wiki are quite clear on both tags. But not even giving people a hint as to what a tag means is a good way of getting it burnt. I think we should throw out a tag if it's being misused because there is no guidance on how it should be used.

Comment: @Mike or someone could suggest a tag wiki

Comment: @TinyGiant Right. Preferably the person who creates the tag. But if there isn't one, you can't really say it's being "misused".

Comment: @mike the point is that you could either make an effort to see if it could be a useful tag, or just forego any effort and just delete the whole thing, which seems unfair to the five followers.

Comment: @TinyGiant So, you're saying that, instead of the person who created the tag, or any of those five followers actually doing the right thing and updating the tag info (since they presumably know what the tag means, or think they do), *I* should do the research so that *they're* not inconvenienced? I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan if you check the tag distribution, of the 32 question with this tag 2 are about javascript, 2 about html, visual-studio and phalcon. They aren't even using the tag consistently.